# vue.js Toast is not defined(while using mint-ui)

Tags: vue.js, webpack

toast is mint-ui component,i already import mint-ui but when i use toast in vue instance will report an error?why?

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import MintUi from 'mint-ui';

import 'mint-ui/lib/style.css'

Vue.use(MintUi);

new Vue({
    el:'#app',
    render:(creater)=> creater(app),
    created(){
        new Toast('hello')  //toast is not defined
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to import Toast from Mint UI.
change `import MintUi from 'mint-ui';` to below.

```
import MintUi, { Toast } from 'mint-ui';
```

Comment: But import MintUi from 'mint-ui' is means  import all component from 'mint-ui' ,so MintUi will contain toast，can i understand in this way?

Comment: Of course, you imported MintUi with `import MintUi from 'mint-ui';` But there is no declaration of Toast. So you should get "Toast" by writing on import. If you want to use Toast without declaration, I guess you can use it like this. `new MintUi.Toast('hello')`

Comment: new MintUi.Toast('hello''') it just use in current page,while using in other page,for example，app.vue，it will report an error 'MintUi' is not defined，i don't know why this mistake appeared

Comment: maybe it caused by scoped?

Comment: check this link first please. https://mint-ui.github.io/docs/#/en2/toast

Comment: When you want to use Toast, you can get Toast by importing like this, `import { Toast } from 'mint-ui';`. if you import with it, webpack let you use Toast Class in that file(not in other file. you should import again. but it will not be duplicated by webpack). Check this too. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import